# Controlling Multiple Elements from a Single Event Listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to toggle classes on 2 elements from a single event listener, but only the first element gets modified.

```
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn");
const slideoutSidebar = document.querySelector(".slideout-sidebar");

const slideTheBar = function () {
  toggleBtn.classList.toggle("toggle-slide");
  slideoutSidebar.classList.toggle("slideout-slide");
};

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", slideTheBar);
```

I have these two elements (toggleBtn, slideoutSidebar) and I have created a function that toggles a class for each element. I then attach this function to an event listener for the toggleBtn element.

The problem is that when the event is executed, only the first line of code of the function is working `toggleBtn.classList.toggle("toggle-slide");`

While the second `slideoutSidebar.classList.toggle("slideout-slide");` is not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks ok, so I guess that your slideoutSidebar does not have the class `slideout-sidebar` or something?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to check out [how to create a mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code seems fine and without knowing more of it, is impossible for us to help you. Have you tried to do a `console.log` after the `toggle()`? Is there any chance there is a typo in the `slideout-slide` class in the css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working fine?

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn");
const slideoutSidebar = document.querySelector(".slideout-sidebar");
console.log(toggleBtn);

const slideTheBar = function () {
  toggleBtn.classList.toggle("toggle-slide");
  slideoutSidebar.classList.toggle("slideout-slide");
};

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", slideTheBar);
```

```css
.slideout-sidebar {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  background: #F05D7C;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.slideout-slide.slideout-slide {

  right: 0
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-btn">Toggle</button>
<div class="slideout-sidebar">Slide me in</div>
```

Comment: Yes, all I needed to do was to add !important on the second class for some reason in CSS! Do I need to do something different if if I want to run the same event listener in multiple elements?

Comment: Not really. May be instead of having an event listener you can just add the function to the html element. Like this <button class="toggle-btn" onclick="slideTheBar()" > Toggle</button>